# Define WebFault in a different namespace / package than the service one (using cxf / jax-ws)

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, cxf

I'm using jax-ws with cxf implementation to implement web services.
I have several services annotated with the @WebService annotation.
In a different package I defined the exceptions (which inherit from RuntimeException) and annotated them with @WebFault with a unique namespace. Each exception class holds a single bean with the exception data (faultInfo) which resides in the same namespace and package as the fault and is annotated with @XMlType.
Example:
Fault Class:

```
@WebFault(name = "GeneralRemoteFault", targetNamespace = WebServices.MyNamespace)
public class GeneralRemoteFault extends RuntimeException
{
    private GeneralRemoteFaultException faultInfo;
    public GeneralRemoteFault(String message, GeneralRemoteFaultException faultInfo) {
        super(message);
        this.faultInfo = faultInfo;
    }
    public GeneralRemoteFault(String message, GeneralRemoteFaultException faultInfo, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
        this.faultInfo = faultInfo;
    }
    public GeneralRemoteFaultException getFaultInfo() {
        return faultInfo;
    }
}
```

Fault Bean: (With package-info which puts it in WebServices.MyNamespace namespace)

```
@XmlType(name = "GeneralRemoteFaultException ")
public class GeneralRemoteFaultException 
{
    private String objId;
    public GeneralRemoteFaultException () {}
    public GeneralRemoteFaultException (String objId)
    {
        this.objId = objId;
    }
    public String getObjId()
    {
        return objId;
    }
    public void setObjId(String objId)
    {
        this.objId = objId;
    }
}
```

The service method:

```
List<ValidationErrors> validateObject(
        @WebParam(name = "object") ValidationObject object,
        @WebParam(name = "groups") String[] groups) throws GeneralRemoteFault;
```

When I run the server CXF complain with the following error:

```
ERROR org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.fillInSchemaCrossreferences:305
[main] - Schema element {http://www.example.com/schema}ValidationRemoteFault references undefined type
{http://www.example.com/schema}ValidationRemoteFaultException for service {http://web_services.example.com/}ValidationService
```

After debugging the code which run the service I've noticed that the schema collection (XmlSchemaCollection.schemas) doesn't include the namespace of the fault bean  and that is why it fails (it contains only the service one's and the fault one's).
It seems that CXF doesn't take into account the option that the fault bean will be defined in a separate namespace than the others and doesn't loads the fault bean schema into the schema collection.
Even if I put the fault bean together in the same namespace with the fault (as defined above), the schema (XmlSchema) for the namespace won't include the JAXB types only the faults.

Any insight about solving the error will be appreciated.

This is the stack of where the message pops from:

```
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection.getTypeByQName(XmlSchemaCollection.java:229)
at org.apache.cxf.common.xmlschema.SchemaCollection.getTypeByQName(SchemaCollection.java:109)
at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.fillInSchemaCrossreferences(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:301)
at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:269)
  - locked <0x1670> (a org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:205)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:101)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ServerFactoryBean.create(ServerFactoryBean.java:159)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServerFactoryBean.java:207)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.getServer(EndpointImpl.java:442)
  - locked <0x1678> (a org.apache.cxf.jaxws22.EndpointImpl)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:329)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:246)
```

Thanks,
  Avner

Comment: Can you please add some code example of your annotated method and fault class?

Comment: I've updated the post with code examples. Thanks

Comment: I did not get this: Your fault class have as `faultInfo` the class `GeneralRemoteFaultException` but you are saying that your fault bean is `ObjectNotFoundRemoteFaultException`. This is not true, your fault bean is `GeneralRemoteFaultException` class. Can you add the code of this class? BTW ... where do you use the `ObjectNotFoundRemoteFaultException` class? Because looking what you put in the `@WebMethod` and the fault class, there is no relation at all. What I meant: If you delete the class `ObjectNotFoundRemoteFaultException` your web service compiles :-P

Comment: Sorry about the mess, I've mixed the wrong code snippet. Fixed that now. I've discovered today that the code actually works beside the fact it logs ugly error messages.

Answer (score 0):

It should work but try forcing JAXB to use the same namespace setting the `namespace` attribute of the `@XmlType` annotation of your fault bean like this

```
@XmlType(name = "GeneralRemoteFaultException ", namespace = WebServices.MyNamespace)
```

Also, you can force your web service class to use the same namespace setting the attribute `targetNamespace` in the `@WebService` annotation like this:

```
@WebService(name = "myService", targetNamespace =  WebServices.MyNamespace)
```

If this not work, please add the resulting WSDL to check the namespace issues.